# processing.js with AngularDart

Tags: dart, angular-dart, p5.js

I discovered a YouTube channel about [p5.js](https://www.youtube.com/user/shiffman). Additionally, I found a [TypeScript project](https://github.com/p5-types) which creates Type definitions.

Below is an [example](https://github.com/p5-types/p5.ts/tree/c29b4390f7221fd1acd744d2335d7520aea80014/examples/webpack-global) for processing.js using TypeScript:

```
import 'script-loader!p5/lib/p5.min.js'
import 'script-loader!p5/lib/addons/p5.dom.min.js'

const x = 100;
const y = 100;

export function setup() {
  createCanvas(200, 200);
  select('canvas')!.position(100, 100);
}

export function draw() {
  background(0);
  fill(255);
  ellipse(x, y, 50, 50);
}
```

How is it possible to convert it to AngularDart?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Processing.js is no longer maintained. I archived it [last december](https://github.com/processing-js/processing-js). However, what you're showing is "p5.js", which is a completely different project. So if the question really is about p5js, please change the tags you used.

Comment: Yes, I meant p5.js